# MVC 4 and Extension Methods with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created an extension method and have included its namespace in my `web.config` file. The extension method works fine and is accesed OK by the test code. The problem is, I am still getting an error relating to the namespace not being found.

The ASP .NET error message I am getting is:

> CS1061: 'System.Uri' does not contain a definition for 'IsCurrentUrl' and no extension method 'IsCurrentUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Uri' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is the respective code.

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="MyMainSite2.Library.Extensions" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Extension method code:

```
namespace MyMainSite2.Library.Extensions
{
    public static class UriExtensions
    {
        #region Public Static Methods

        public static bool IsCurrentUrl(this Uri uri, string url)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                return false;

            url = url.Trim().ToLower();
            string absolutePath = uri.AbsolutePath.Trim().ToLower();

            if (!url.StartsWith("/") && absolutePath.StartsWith("/"))
                absolutePath = absolutePath.Remove(0, 1);

            bool match = absolutePath == url;

            return match;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Razor code:

```
@model MyMainSite2.UI.Web.Models.Shared.TopMenuModel

@foreach (var item in this.Model.Items)
{
    if(this.Request.Url.IsCurrentUrl(item.Url)) // this line is failing because UriExtensions.IsCurrentUrl is not being found
    {
        @:<li class="current">
    }
    else
    {
        @:<li>
    }

    @:<a href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>
}
```

Comment: Have you got the right using statement in the view file?

Comment: No. I am putting the namespace in the web.config so that I don't have to do this for each view file.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `MyMainSite2.Library.Extensions.UriExtensions`?

Comment: What do you have in mind to change?

Comment: Try changing the namespace declaration to `MyMainSite2.Library.Extensions.UriExtensions` in the web.config, or just removing that entirely and including it in the view to see if it is found.

Comment: Adding the namespace to the view works fine. My aim though is to have it globally accessible to all view.

Comment: Which web config file are u adding namespace to? Views or main?

Comment: That was the answer, thank you! I was adding the namespace to the main Web.config rather than the view's Web.config

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer was given by petro.sidlovskyy.

I was adding the namespace to the main Web.config rather than the view's Web.config.

When I added the namespace to the Web.config in the Views folder, the namespace was recognised by the view, and thus the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to post that I have been having this issue for a good few months now, and I followed the guide on the ASP.NET site, line by line, and I was able to get Intellisense back for Razor files.

Here is the link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I hope this helps prevent other people losing their hair as well.